# Compile and run program from Kotlin REPL

Tags: kotlin, command-line, compilation, read-eval-print-loop

I currently compile and run Kotlin programs on the command line using kotlinc, like
`konlinc program.kt -include-runtime -d program.jar && jave -jar program.jar`

This takes a few seconds to presumably load the compiler into memory each time, give the standard warnings (e.g. All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release) and then starts to compile the program.

As a result, even for a hello world program it takes a couple of seconds.

Is there a way I can do this faster? Compiling and running from the REPL might be a faster way, but I don't know if Kotlin allows that. I don't want to use an IDE.

Comment: There is also the online playground: https://play.kotlinlang.org

Comment: kotlinc without any parameters starts the REPL.Can't try it out at the moment. But Kotlin's REPL is not good compared to Scala's REPL. The recommendation of the makers of Kotlin is to use an IDE.

Comment: @Twistleton I am familiar with the online playground, but I would prefer a local solution. Indeed, `kotlinc` or `kotlin` starts the REPL. How can I compile program (files) from the REPL? I agree, Kotlin REPL is terrible compared to many others. IDEs might be necessary for large projects but are overkill for small things, which are much better managed via the terminal..

Comment: yogesch did you find a solution to this? what about with a dockerfile?

Comment: Hi, no, I switched to React Native shortly after.